# NSDisctionary to mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json, syntax, asihttprequest

I have a NSDictionary that looks like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Movies", @"Category", @"Swedish", @"Language" , nil];
```

I'm converting that to a JSON representation, after that, the string looks like this:

```
{"Category":"Movies","Language":"Swedish"}
```

I'm uploading that to my server using ASIHTTPRequest (POST-method) and now I want to input this into my database. I'm not getting it to work. I'm using this loop but it inserts both values on both columns:

```
$decoded = strip_tags(json_decode($_POST['NSDict']));
```

//Making connection to DB here

```
foreach ($decoded as $value) {
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO testtable (category, language) VALUES ('".$value."', '".$value."')") or die(mysql_error());

    echo $result;
}
```

How should I modify my PHP to insert Movies in to category and Swedish into language?

//Thanks!

---

ok.. this worked:

```
<?php

$decoded = json_decode($_POST['Hej']);
//echo $decoded->{'Language'};


$link = mysql_connect("localhost","","");
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $link);
mysql_select_db("quizerDB");

foreach ($decoded as $name => $value) {

$value = json_decode(json_encode($value),true);

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO testtable (category, language) VALUES ('".$value['Category']."', '".$value['Language']."')") or die(mysql_error());

echo $result;

}

?>
```

is there anything here I could do better? missing in security etc.??

Comment: You first need to fix the SQL-injection hole!

Comment: This is for schoolwork and doesn't run on computer connected to the internet so it's irrelevant.. Can you help with the foreach-loop?

Comment: you have just earned my complete disrespect. I can but I don't want to.

Comment: oh, I'm sorry. Didn't mean to offend you. just needed to get the loop working.. it's been driving me a bit crazy. Once again, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

if you try print_r($decoded); you can see the structure of the decoded JSON string.
I'm assuming that it returns std_object's instead of an array.

I'm guessing you should be able to do $value->category and $value->Language to get the data you want.

---

if you use this code.

```
$json = '{"Category":"Movies","Language":"Swedish"}';
$decoded = json_decode($json);

print_r($decoded);
```

you can see that it returns this.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Category] => Movies
    [Language] => Swedish
)
```

if you foreach through this you will only get "Movies" and and "Swedish" in each loop. you have to make your JSON decode into an array with the stdClass objects if you want to loop through them.

$decoded->Category; and $decoded->Language; will return "Movies" and "Swedish" respectively.

Comment: Like this: foreach ($decoded as $value) {
   $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO testtable (category, language) VALUES ('".$value->{'Category'}."', '".$value{'Language'}."')") or die(mysql_error());
   echo $result;

  }   I doesn't write anything to the DB. Errors.

Comment: you should try print_r($value); to see if there is actually anything in there. If you get null then you should go back to print_r($decoded); and check the value there again.

Comment: Yes, it contains this: MoviesSwedish

Comment: But how do I write them to the database, syntax?